# Someone killed chat!

Tags: bug, chat

When I try to connect to chat, either Meta or SE chat, I get an "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error. Using Chrome latest.

[image]

---

Aaaand it's back. Thank you, oh SE dev :)

Comment: I think it is back.

Comment: We are looking into why that HAProxy instance cycled (or rather *tried* to cycle) now.

Comment: @NickCraver Feel free to reopen and post something about what happened if you'd like

Comment: It turns out an errant `pkill -u root -f /opt/haproxy/$BASENAME` was killing `haproxy-t20` when we intended `haproxy-t2` only. We're seeing how this never happened before.